# RSpec Couldn't find with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I'm writing an RSpec controller test and I've run into the following problem.

The relationship is such that Invoices belong to a Purchase, and a Purchase has many invoices.

My controller has:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
  end

  def new
    @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:purchase])
    @invoice = Invoice.new(:purchase_id => params[:purchase])
  end
```

My factory has:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do |f|
    sequence(:id) { |number| number }
    f.purchase_id {rand(1..30)}
    f.number { FFaker::String.from_regexp(/\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\z/) }
    f.terms { FFaker::String.from_regexp(/\A[A-Za-z0-9\s]+\z/) }
    f.currency { FFaker::String.from_regexp(/\A[A-Z]+\z/) }
    f.total_due {'25000.00'}
    f.current_balance {'12500.00'}
    f.due_date { FFaker::Time.date }
    f.notes { FFaker::HipsterIpsum.paragraph }
    f.status {[:open, :paid, :canceled].sample}
    purchase
  end

  factory :invalid_invoice, parent: :invoice do |f|
    f.status nil
  end
end
```

My controller spec (just the problematic part) has:

```
describe "GET new" do
    it "assigns a new invoice to @invoice" do
      invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice)
      get :new
      expect(assigns(:invoice)).to_not eq(invoice)
    end

    it "renders the :new template" do
      get :new
      expect(response).to render_template :new
    end
  end
```

In my routes I have:

```
purchases GET                       /purchases(.:format)                        purchases#index
                                 POST                      /purchases(.:format)                        purchases#create
                    new_purchase GET                       /purchases/new(.:format)                    purchases#new
                   edit_purchase GET                       /purchases/:id/edit(.:format)               purchases#edit
                        purchase GET                       /purchases/:id(.:format)                    purchases#show
                                 PATCH                     /purchases/:id(.:format)                    purchases#update
                                 PUT                       /purchases/:id(.:format)                    purchases#update
                                 DELETE                    /purchases/:id(.:format)                    purchases#destroy

invoices GET                       /invoices(.:format)                         invoices#index
                                 POST                      /invoices(.:format)                         invoices#create
                     new_invoice GET                       /invoices/new(.:format)                     invoices#new
                    edit_invoice GET                       /invoices/:id/edit(.:format)                invoices#edit
                         invoice GET                       /invoices/:id(.:format)                     invoices#show
                                 PATCH                     /invoices/:id(.:format)                     invoices#update
                                 PUT                       /invoices/:id(.:format)                     invoices#update
                                 DELETE                    /invoices/:id(.:format)                     invoices#destroy
```

When I run the test I get this:

```
1) InvoicesController GET new assigns a new invoice to @invoice
     Failure/Error: get :new
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Purchase with 'id'=
     # ./app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:7:in `new'
     # ./spec/controllers/invoices_controller_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) InvoicesController GET new renders the :new template
     Failure/Error: get :new
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Purchase with 'id'=
     # ./app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb:7:in `new'
     # ./spec/controllers/invoices_controller_spec.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is a snippet from test.log

[1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "purchases" ("id", "vendor_id", "order_number", "status", "notes", "tradegecko_url", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"[0m  [["id", 4], ["vendor_id", 4], ["order_number", "zzz"], ["status", "canceled"], ["notes", "Jean shorts cliche Williamsburg raw denim put a bird on it messenger bag. Shoreditch keytar Brooklyn lomo brunch. Mcsweeney's Cosby Sweater +1 PBR Austin biodiesel freegan."], ["tradegecko_url", "http://gorczany.info"], ["created_at", "2016-07-19 14:51:00.616108"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-19 14:51:00.616108"]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "invoices" ("id", "purchase_id", "number", "terms", "currency", "total_due", "current_balance", "due_date", "notes", "status", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 4], ["purchase_id", 4], ["number", "dd"], ["terms", "TT"], ["currency", "MM"], ["total_due", "25000.0"], ["current_balance", "12500.0"], ["due_date", "2015-11-13"], ["notes", "Scenester Carles cred quinoa fixie put a bird on it Four Loko next level. Biodiesel vice Wayfarers sustainable brunch butcher locavore. Keytar vice next level stumptown Rerry Richardson."], ["status", "canceled"], ["created_at", "2016-07-19 14:51:00.619066"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-19 14:51:00.619066"]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
Processing by InvoicesController#new as HTML
  [1m[35mPurchase Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT  "purchases".* FROM "purchases" WHERE "purchases"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

I think the problem is that the factory associations are created, but not saved. So when the purchase.id is called it returns nil.

Comment: This error says that you're doing this: `ModelXYZ.find(<id>)` and the id is not persisted. (RecordNotFound) Please post your routes to help us out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try and help me. I understand what the error is saying, what I can't figure out is how to fix it. I've tried creating a purchase record with FactoryGirl before the example, but that didn't work, I still had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to load a purchase in the `new` action:

```
  def new
    @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:purchase])
    @invoice = Invoice.new(:purchase_id => params[:purchase])
  end
```

but in your test you are not passing a `:purchase` parameter (should be :purchase_id i guess)!

Comment: Right. In the actual app, an invoice can only be created from a purchase, so that purchase_id is passed to the invoice being created. In the test I have tried manually creating a purchase before the example, I've tried using FactoryGirl to create the purchase before the example. Still I cannot get the purchase_id passed to the new invoice.

Comment: well.. maybe try harder? so what exactly did you try then?

Comment: could also be helpful to look into the contents of log/test.log when running your tests

Comment: Haha! I've been trying. Still at it.

Comment: I added a test.log snippet. The associated purchase is generated by FactoryGirl, but not saved, so when the purchase.id is called it returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

The associations stated in the factories were not persisting, resulting in a nil value for the Purchase.id.

So after trying before callbacks, after callbacks, traits, I gave up on using FactoryGirl's auto-generated associations.

In the end this is what I had to do:

I removed all stated associations from the factories, then did it manually, the edited code in the spec:

```
describe "GET new" do

    it "assigns a new invoice to @invoice" do
      invoice = FactoryGirl.create(:invoice)
      get :new, purchase: FactoryGirl.create(:purchase)
      expect(assigns(:invoice)).to_not eq(invoice)
    end

    it "renders the :new template" do
      get :new, purchase: FactoryGirl.create(:purchase)
      expect(response).to render_template :new
    end
  end
```

I hope this helps anyone else who comes across this problem.

Comment: f.purchase_id {rand(1..30)} I think this is your problem or part of it.  your factory is creating a random purchase id

Comment: Can you add the auto-generated `purchase` back into your factory and then change your call to `get` like so? `get :new, purchase: invoice.purchase`

Comment: Doon - I tried removing that line, and when that didn't work I changed it to a sequence, still the same error.

Comment: Chris, I did try that earlier, and got an undefined method 'purchase' error.